# Unable to mount S3 on EC2 using RIOFS - HTTP error: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, fuse, s3fs

I am trying to mount S3 bucket on AWS EC2 instance using RIOFS. I am unsuccessful.

Here is the logs

```
12:47:53 [main] (main main.c:753) Using config file: /home/ubuntu/.config/riofs/riofs.conf.xml
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_init http_connection.c:79) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com:80
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_make_request http_connection.c:814) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] GET /csv-test/?acl  bucket: csv-test, host: s3.amazonaws.com, out_len: 0
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_response_cb http_connection.c:464) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Got HTTP response from server! (160msec)
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_response_cb http_connection.c:544) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] New URL: csv-test.s3.amazonaws.com
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_init http_connection.c:79) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Connecting to csv-test.s3.amazonaws.com:80
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_close http_connection.c:196) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Connection closed !
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_make_request http_connection.c:814) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] GET /?acl  bucket: csv-test, host: csv-test.s3.amazonaws.com, out_len: 0
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_close http_connection.c:196) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Connection closed !
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_response_cb http_connection.c:464) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Got HTTP response from server! (9msec)
12:47:53 [con] (http_connection_on_response_cb http_connection.c:591) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Server returned HTTP error: 400 (Bad Request). AWS message: The authorization mechanism you have provided is not supported. Please use AWS4-HMAC-SHA256.
12:47:53 [con]  (http_connection_on_response_cb http_connection.c:602) [con: 0x561ff22c2be0] Server returned HTTP error: 400 (Bad Request)! Retry ID: 1 of 20
```

Is there a way to enable the use of `AWS4-HMAC-SHA256` in RIOFS connection. I am trying this in Frankfurt `eu-central-1` and also in London `eu-west-2` and unsuccessful in both the regions.

I also tried using s3fs and ended with unable to access bucket error but couldn't get detailed logs like riofs which pointed out the actual error.

Comment: Can you run s3fs again with the flags `-f -d`?

Comment: @Andrew I have fixed this now.  The same options works with buckets created on us-east-1

Comment: Newer AWS regions only support AWS signature v4.  Newer versions of s3fs should support and indeed default to v4.  Can you share which version of s3fs you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 is Signature Version 4 and only few regions support it. I tested this against Frankfurt eu-central-1 and London eu-west-2.  Both these region doesn't work.  It works only on US-EAST-1 N. Virginia region.

I could successfully mount the S3 bucket created on us-east-1 on EC2.